# Greensock-TweenLite-Max preserve resolution of nested bitmap

Tags: actionscript-3, gsap

I have a 1920x1080 bitmap which I have scaled to fit in a much smaller 'thumbnail' MovieClip.

I then have scaled up this MovieClip to the bitmap's original 1920x1080 size using TweenLite
Problem is the bitmap appears quite blurry.

Is there a way to preserve the original resolution of a nested bitmap when you scale this way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can also use the actionscript [Bitmap smoothing property](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Bitmap.html#smoothing) before you scale it,
by setting `bitmap.smoothing = true;`